# Checking if columns in dataframe are "paired"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very long data frame (~10,000 rows), in which two of the columns look something like this.

```
  A     B
  1   5.5
  1   5.5
  2   201
  9    18
  9    18
  2   201
  9    18
...   ...
```

Just scrubbing through the data it seems that the two columns are "paired" together, but is there any way of explicitly checking this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'paired'?  is that for each value of A there is only one value of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know if value x in column A always means value y in column B?
Let's group by A and count the distinct values in B:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 1, 2, 9, 9, 2, 9),
  B = c(5.5, 5.5, 201, 18, 18, 201, 18)
)

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  distinct(B) %>%
  summarize(n_unique = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      A n_unique
  <dbl>    <int>
1     1        1
2     2        1
3     9        1
```

If we now alter the df to the case that this is not true:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 1, 2, 9, 9, 2, 9),
  B = c(5.5, 5.4, 201, 18, 18, 201, 18)
)

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  distinct(B) %>%
  summarize(n_unique = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      A n_unique
  <dbl>    <int>
1     1        2
2     2        1
3     9        1
```

Observe the increased count for group 1. As you have more than 10000 rows, what remains is to see whether or not there is at least one instance that has n_unique > 1, for instance by filter(n_unique > 1)

Answer (score 0):

If you run this you will see how many unique values of `B` there are for each value of `A`

```
tapply(dat$B, dat$A, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

So if the max of this vector is 1 then there are no values of `A` that have more than one corresponding value of `B`.